# Adding "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" uses Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a question for my understanding:

When I add a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to my Console-Application, Visual Studio 2017 will use the Entity Framework 6.1.3 from NuGet. Why is it not using the newest Version (resp. the on NuGet as "Current Version" marked) of Entity Framework (6.2.0)?

Comment: Cause you didn't install it(?)

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, is the version fix set to 6.1.3 in Visual Studio 2017 when I install Entity Framework 6-Tools?

Comment: The version automatically installed isn't the latest build, but the recommended one, if i'm not wrong you can change it

Comment: with 15.7 update you'll get the 6.2 tools.see my updated answer with the link to 15.7 preview release notes.

Comment: Microsoft released the 15.7 update, here you should see 6.2 nuget references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curently (as on writing on 2018-04-23) the EF6 tools are version 6.1.3, the [last EF6 runtime is 6.2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/26/entity-framework-6-2-runtime-released/).

> **Where are the EF 6.2 tools for Visual Studio?**
>
> We decided that we still needed to complete some work on the tools
>   before we could declare them “final”. However, it did not make sense
>   to delay the release of the runtime packages:
>
> - The EF 6.2 runtime is fully compatible with released versions of our Visual Studio tools. You should only need to manually upgrade the
>     NuGet packages in your applications.

In the repository I can see the [tag for 6.2 tools](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/releases/tag/6.2.0). With [Visual Studio 2017 15.7 you'll get the EF 6.2 tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes#EFTools)

> Support for the Entity Framework 6.2 Runtime: Creating an EF model in
>   a project that does not reference EF will now install the EF 6.2 NuGet
>   package by default.

Currently with Visual Studio 2017 Update 15.6.x update the nuget packages to 6.2 until the 6.2 tools gets released with 15.7 update.